# Can't align large image in center of a smaller div with overflow hidden along with caption effect

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, youtube

My question has three parts

Part 1:  To show an animated image caption for a image (this part is done as in the example row one http://jsfiddle.net/JBnbG/32/ )

Part 2: Show center part of youtube `hqdefault.jpg` thumbnail image in a div of 150x150 dimension (This part is also done as second row in the example)

Part 3: I want to integrate the part 1 & part 2 features in to part 3. problem is that caption works but the image is not alined in center as show in second row of the example.

Example is in http://jsfiddle.net/JBnbG/32/

I cant change structure otherwise it wont work caption part work properly

I would appreciate if some can help to fix the issue with keeping the HTML structure intact

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check this working code: http://jsfiddle.net/surendraVsingh/JBnbG/39/

**Changes to be done in CSS:**

```
.VideoContainer  > span {
    display: block;    
}
.VideoContainer > span > img {
    display: inline-block;
    margin-left: -60px;
    margin-top: -25px;
}
```

Comment: Thanks i have to mark your answer as correct as it works with all the image

Answer (score 1):

I guess my question is, are you loading the example html dynamically from youtube, or just the images?

If the html is yours, it's a simple styling adjustment.

I forked  it on [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/son0fhobs/VrFQR/6/) , I think this is what you mean.

Not quite sure what happened to the styling, but I set the image

```
id="ContentPlaceHolder1_rptVideos_imgVideo_1" style="height:auto; width:200px;margin-left:-25px;"
```

or, another way is:

```
left:-25px; position:relative;
```

Which btw, all these styles should be declared as a class in you stylesheet.

If you're loading the html dynamically, I commented out the javascript that achieves the same thing.

Depending on what you're working with, if using php, you might want to get a script that will auto crop to the appropriate size.  Timthumb.php is the most notable one, although there's a security issue that will never be fully bulletproof, although pretty solid as is.

Cheers!

Comment: Thanks, I have given your answer upvote as it only works with one image. I am actually storing the youtube Video ID in database and from their i am dynamically creating Video Icon in a asp.net Repeater control. anyways appreciate your answer

Comment: So Does that mean the image size will change each implementation?  I only fixed one image in my jsfiddle to examplify my answer but assumed you could modify it as needed for the others.  If the height is also off center, apply the same concept to height, using a negative margin to align it.  

Another way to center an element, in any situation, is margin-left:50%;left:-[1/2 the width of the image. ] in this case: left:-134.5px;